# Nginx: Using $ssl_server_name in the ssl_certificate path has errors, but hardcoding the same value works

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm trying to set up an Nginx server that will eventually have many domains pointed at it.

I created a LetsEncrypt certificate for the domain I'm testing right now, but I'm running into problems getting Nginx to use it.

When I have my server set up like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$ssl_server_name/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/$ssl_server_name/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        add_header Content-Type text/html;
        return 200 $ssl_server_name;
    }
}
```

I get this error in the Nginx error.log when I try to visit the site:

```
2023/11/07 05:55:40 [error] 1706#1706: *52 cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:8000000D:system library::Permission denied:calling fopen(/etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com/fullchain.pem, r) error:10080002:BIO routines::system lib) while SSL handshaking, client: [my ip address], server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

However, if I hardcode the path to the certificate like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        add_header Content-Type text/html;
        return 200 $ssl_server_name;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly. Visiting the site returns the response `test.example.com`. It seems like somehow `$ssl_server_name` has the correct value, but loading the ssl certificate with a variable in the path causes it to not load properly.

The server is a VPS running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, fully updated. Nginx is version 1.18.0.

I know that I could probably set up some sort of template that would be used to make a new config file for each domain that I want to set up, but I would much prefer if I could get this single config approach to work.

Comment: Can the user running Nginx (maybe `nginx` or `www`) read the certificate files? When you use the hardcoded values, Nginx reads the file when just starting, and it's possible that it has elevated privileges when starting.

Comment: @RichardSmith I checked and there is a process "nginx: master process" running as root and "nginx: worker process" running as www-data, so that may indeed be the problem. Is there anything wrong with changing the permissions in the /etc/letsencrypt folder to allow www-data to read the files, or will I just have to make a template server config that I copy for each domain that I want to support?